# Como fazer uma função que "chama" um html

Tags: javascript, html

Estou me aprimorando no html e JavaScript ao mesmo tempo que crio um projeto meu. Não sei se minha pergunta está da forma correta, mas estarei explicando da melhor forma.

Estou criando uma ferramenta para auxiliar os turnos de combate em RPG de mesa, para isso estou usando html e css para criar cards contendo informações dos personagens e monstros, só que o código acaba ficando enorme e com muitas linhas repetidas.

Os cards estão seguindo esse padrão:

```
<!-- Iniciando o card -->
 <div class="boards">
   <div class="board">
     <h3> 1º </h3>
     <input placeholder="Nome" class="inpNome">
     <div class="dropzone">
       <div class="card" draggable="true">
         
 <!-- Informações dentro do card -->
         <img src="" alt="" width="260" height="200">

         <div class="areaSaude">
           <button class="btnDano">Dano</button>
           <input type="number" min="0" class="inpValor">
           <button class="btnCura">Cura</button>
         </div>

         <div class="area">
           <div class="status">
             <div class="status-life"></div>
             <div class="grid-barra">
                <div class="heartLifeBar"> 
                  <img id="heart" src="./view/imagens/heartLifeBar.png" alt="coração" />
                </div>
                <div class="total">
                  <input placeholder="0" class="varLife">
                  <span class="spnBar">/</span>
                  <input placeholder="0" class="lifeTotal">
                </div>
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>

         <div class="area">
           <div class="status">
             <div class="status-shield"></div>
             <div class="grid-barra">
                <div class="shieldMob"> 
                  <img id="EscudoMob" src="./view/imagens/shield.svg" alt="Escudo" />
                </div>
                <div class="total-shield">
                 <input placeholder="0" class="varEscudo">
                 <span class="spnBar">/</span>
                 <input placeholder="0" class="escudoTotal">
                </div>
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>

         <div class="containerSentido">
             <div class="sentidos">
                 <img class="sentido1" src="./view/imagens/senses.svg" alt="Sentidos" />
                     <div class="percepcao">Perception</div>
                     <div class="numPercepcao">15</div>
                 <img class="sentido1" src="./view/imagens/senses.svg" alt="Sentidos" />
                     <div class="percepcao">Investigation</div>
                     <div class="numPercepcao">12</div>
                 <img class="sentido1" src="./view/imagens/senses.svg" alt="Sentidos" />
                     <div class="percepcao">Insight</div>
                     <div class="numPercepcao">13</div>
              </div>
         </div>  

<!-- Fim do conteúdo -->

     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
 </div>
<!-- Fim do card -->
```

Com isso estava pensando numa forma de salvar as informações dos mobs prontas em outro arquivo para diminuir o tamanho do código. Tipo ter vários arquivos html contendo informações de mobs diferentes, exemplo: `minotaur.html`, `goblin.html` ..., e deixar apenas o card vazio no código principal pronto para receber as informações do monstro ou personagem clicando em um botão.
Dessa forma:

```
<!-- Iniciando o card -->
  <div class="boards">
    <div class="board">
      <h3> 6º </h3>
      <input placeholder="Nome" class="inpNome">
      <div class="dropzone">
        <div class="card" draggable="true">

       <!-- Informações dentro do card -->
          
         <button onClick="puxar informações">    

       <!-- Fim do conteúdo -->  

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 <!-- Fim do card -->
```

Aceito dicas de como melhorar o código, como resolver o problema, links para estudar.

Comment: Aparentemente você pode usar o `template` e o `slot`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_templates_and_slots.

Answer (score -2):

Tudo bem?
Vamos lá ver, pelo que eu entendi você quer carregar num botão e mudar as informações do html, certo? Se for isso que você quer fazer, eu posso dar um exemplo:

```
<html>
<body>

<h2>carta</h2>

<p>Dano:</p><b id="damage"></b>

<button type="button" onclick='document.getElementById("damage").innerHTML = "110"'>monstro 1</button>

<button type="button" onclick='document.getElementById("damage").innerHTML = "250"'>monstro 2</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tá mais para pegar o trecho do código contendo informações do card em outro arquivo html e renderizar ela no card. Mas o que você disse tbm é bem útil.